# How to listen to a streaming API in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, streaming

I am making a middleware in Spring Boot. There is an API which has an endpoint that streams data. I have to listen to that data & expose an endpoint in the middleware which passes that streaming data from my middleware to the front-end. So, the whole process will be like this, when the front-end will make a request to my middleware. My middleware will open a persistent connection to the streaming API endpoint & whatever the data API returns, the middleware will pass it to the front-end.

My main problem is I am not able to figure out how to perfectly listen to the streaming API in my Spring Boot middleware. What will we use?
WebSocket? WebClient? & how?

Can someone give a basic idea with a basic sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.
We can use WebClient & Flux to get the streaming data.

To start streaming:

```
  private final WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

  public Flux<String> startStreaming() {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("STREAMING API END POINT")
            .header("Authorization","Bearer "+Key.BearerToken)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(String.class); ///String.class or any other custom model class can be used.
}
```